# Error on Save Did not Save. SecureComponent: markup://c:QuestionIteration {691:0}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

**Update 2 pm MT July 26**

As I stripped away code looking for issues, I noticed that the component saves when fields are not auto-populated.

Removing `<lightning:select name="departmentSelect"  . . .` and it's `<aura:iteration>`, as well as the `<aura:iteration>` over `{!v.questions}` allows for save.

Moreover, removing `survey.Survey_Date__c =`${day}-${month}-${year}`;` in `getQuestions` and selecting date manually, allows for successful save.

Seems that auto-populated values are the problem, but I have not idea why!

**Edited to include component markup**

I'm getting an error on save that I've never seen before:

```
Did not Save. SecureComponent: markup://c:QuestionIteration {691:0}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
```

I think it's important to note, as well, that the component will save before I select a department from the dropdown and trigger the onchange `c.selectDept` action. (I modify the save code as necessary for this to succeed.) Nothing jumps out at me in that code, but I'll include it below as well. It calls the helper `getQuestions`

I don't have a unique namespace set up, so "c" should be good. I don't understand what the error means, though.

Here is the code I'm using for save, which has worked in other components:

**Component Markup**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" controller="QuestionIterationController" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="FFS_Key_Area_Bank__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="questions" type="FFS_Key_Area_Bank__c[]" default="[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="departments" type="Department__c[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="results" type="FFS_Result__c" default="[{ 'sobjectType' :
                                                                   'FFS_Result__c',
                                                                   'Key_Area_Bank__c' : '',
                                                                   'Rating__c' : ''}]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="survey" type="FFS_Survey__c" default="{ 'sobjectType' :
                                                                  'FFS_Survey__c',
                                                                  'Name' : '',
                                                                  'Survey_Date__c' : ''}" />

    <aura:attribute name="departmentSelected" type="String"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />


    <lightning:layout verticalAlign="center">
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-medium">
            <lightning:card class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner"
                            iconName="action:new_group" title="Hi Department List">
                    <lightning:select name="departmentSelect"
                                      label="Choose a Department"
                                      aura:id="departmentSelect"
                                      value="{!v.departmentSelected}"
                                      onchange="{!c.selectDept}">
                        <option value="" >Please select a department</option>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.departments}" var="dept">
                            <option value="{!dept.Name}" text="{!dept.Name}" selected="{!dept.selected}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small"  label="Save" title="Submit Button" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
            </lightning:card>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

    <lightning:layout verticalAlign="center">
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-medium">
            <lightning:card class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner"
                            iconName="action:new_group" title="Survey">
                <lightning:input label      ="FFS Name"
                                 name       ="FFSName"
                                 aura:id    = "FFSName"
                                 value      ="{!v.survey.Name}" />

                <lightning:input label      ="Date"
                                 name       ="Date"
                                 aura:id    ="SurveyDate"
                                 value      ="{!v.survey.Survey_Date__c}"
                                 type       ="date"
                                 class="slds-m-top_small"/>

                <aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="questions">
                    <lightning:layout>
                        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning:input label="Key Area"
                                             value="{!questions.FFS_Key_Area__c}"
                                             name="ffsQuestions"
                                             aura:id="ffsQuestions"/>
                            <lightning:input label="Rating"
                                             value="{!questions.Rating__c}"
                                             aura:id="qRating"
                                             name="qRating"
                                             type="number"/>
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </lightning:layout>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:card>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

**JavaScript Controller**

getQuestions is the helper for `selectDept`

```
    getQuestions : function (component) {
let department = component.find("departmentSelect").get("v.value");


            let action = component.get("c.retrieveQuestions");
            action.setParams({
                departmentSelected : department
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
                let state = result.getState();
                if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                    component.set("v.questions", result.getReturnValue());
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);

            let survey = component.get("v.survey");
            let surveyDate = new Date();
            let month = surveyDate.getMonth();
            let day = surveyDate.getDate();
            let year = surveyDate.getFullYear();

            survey.Name = `${department} Formula For Success ${day}/${month}/${year}`;
            survey.Survey_Date__c = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
            component.set("v.survey", survey);
        },
```

(newSurvey is a helper that is called on `c.handleClick`)

```
newSurvey : function (component) {
        let newSurvey = component.get("v.survey");
        let newResults = component.get("v.results");

        let action = component.get("c.createSurvey");
        action.setParams({ "survey" : newSurvey, "results" : newResults });

        action.setCallback(this, function (response, error) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // let name = response.getReturnValue();
                let toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success!",
                    "message": "The Survey has been successfully saved."
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
                // $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

            } else {
                alert('Did not Save. ' + error);
                console.log("Unsuccessful Save");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
     }
```

**Apex Controller**

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean createSurvey(FFS_Survey__c survey, List<FFS_Result__c> results) {
        insert survey;
        for(FFS_Result__c result: results) {
            result.FFS_Survey__c = survey.Id;
        }
        insert results;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to post your component markup as well?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. Was hoping the error message might mean something on it's own. I'll edit the question to include all the code now.

Comment: Just added component markup

Comment: Added getQuestions controller markup. Not sure if it's important, but I can save the record before calling the helper. (See above.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several custom objects, so it is difficult to replicate on my end, so I am going to shoot in the dark here.

`results` parameter in this method expects a `List<FFS_Result__c>`:

```
public static Boolean createSurvey(FFS_Survey__c survey, List<FFS_Result__c> results)
```

but looks like you defined it as a non-List in your component markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="results" type="FFS_Result__c" default="[{ 'sobjectType' :
                                                                   'FFS_Result__c',
                                                                   'Key_Area_Bank__c' : '',
                                                                   'Rating__c' : ''}]"/>
```

so try changing it to an array removing default?

```
<aura:attribute name="results" type="FFS_Result__c[]"/>
```

Obviously this isn't your full code, so not sure where you are setting `results` attribute. Hope that is returning `List<FFS_Result__c>` type.

This is a long shot to work, but if it doesn't would you be able to spin up a simple small generic component pin-pointing the exact problem so we can replicate on our end and suggest a fix?

And oh, on a side note, I noticed that you are implementing `force:hasRecordId`, but specify this:

`<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="FFS_Key_Area_Bank__c[]" />` instead of `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>` Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't solve the problem. Thanks for giving it a shot. I did notice something as I searched for the issue: I'll spare all of the details, but if none of the fields are auto-populated, the component saves successfully. So, removing departmentSelect <lightning:select> and questions <aura:iteration>, replacing with input fields, saves with manual input. I'll update question with this.

Comment: Do you see the error message in an alert? Meaning: alert('Did not Save. ' + error); is executed in newSurvey method? That would mean that state is not SUCCESS, so perhaps the Apex class failed? Try putting your class method in a try-catch and look at debug logs?

Comment: Ok! Here's what happened: I added the try-catch and I received a success message. The survey saved. The results, however, did not. This the message from the debug log: 14:54:52:046 USER_DEBUG [40]|DEBUG|The following exception has occurredInsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MALFORMED_ID, Key Area Bank: id value of incorrect type: Admin Question 1: [Key_Area_Bank__c]. Gives us something to work on.

Comment: In your results attribute, you have defaulted 'Key_Area_Bank__c' to ''. You must be overriding the results from somewhere. In that case, are you sure Key_Area_Bank__c is being set correctly? If not, because it seems to be a lookup field, a blank string value could be rejected by Apex.

Comment: Also, see what result.Key_Area_Bank__c prints in a debug statement within the for loop of your Apex createSurvey method. That should narrow it down further.

Comment: It's working! First issue was passing the Name into Key_Area_Bank__c instead of the Id. Then the error changed to say 'required field Rating__c' was null. I had named it 'Result__c' on accident. So, in the end, my rookie mistakes. Thanks for the advice on the try-catch!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the suggestions by @Kal and subsequent troubleshooting. Check his first suggestion and the comments on that suggestion.

Main points:

@Kal - "Do you see the error message in an alert? Meaning: alert('Did not Save. ' + error); is executed in newSurvey method? That would mean that state is not SUCCESS, so perhaps the Apex class failed? Try putting your class method in a try-catch and look at debug logs?"

Me - "First issue was passing the Name into Key_Area_Bank__c instead of the Id. Then the error changed to say 'required field Rating__c' was null. I had named it 'Result__c' on accident. So, in the end, my rookie mistakes. Thanks for the advice on the try-catch!"